# Recorrer letras del titulo con CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando unas practicas escolares y uno titulo de un párrafo no pude recorrerlo para que salga centrado.

[image: Quiero recorrer el titulo de párrafo Desayuno y quiero centrarlo]

```
   <article>
       <p class="categoriaDesa">Desayunos</p>
         <div class="platillo">
           <p class="nombre"> Moyetes Clasicos</p>
           <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
           <p class="descripcion"> Tradicionales molletes; bolillo con mantequilla, frijoles refritos y queso manchego o si lo prefiere puede agregar ingrediente extra de su elección.</p>
        </div>


         </article>





.main .menu .categoriaDesa{

background: rgba(03,03,03,.45);
padding-right: 920px;

color: white;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 100px;
margin-bottom: 40px ;  /*inicio del margen inferior */ 
text-align: justify;


}
```

---

```
.main .menu .categoriaDesa{
background: rgba(03,03,03,.45);
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 100px;
margin-bottom: 40px ;  /*inicio del margen inferior */ 
padding-right: 920px;

}

article > .categoriaDesa{
text-align: center;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: elimina ese `padding-right: 920px;` y ya está, centrado.

Answer (score 0):

Para centrar **p** es recomendable iniciar el selector desde **div** que lo contiene, ya que centrar directamente a **p** aparentemente no muestra cambio.

```css
.main .menu .categoriaDesa{
    background: rgba(03,03,03,.45);
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 40px ;  /*inicio del margen inferior */ 
    padding-right: 920px;
    text-align: justify;
}

article > .categoriaDesa{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article>
           <p class="categoriaDesa">Desayunos</p>
             <div class="platillo">
               <p class="nombre"> Moyetes Clasicos</p>
               <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
               <p class="descripcion"> Tradicionales molletes; bolillo con mantequilla, frijoles refritos y queso manchego o si lo prefiere puede agregar ingrediente extra de su elección.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="platillo">
               <p class="nombre"> Moyetes Clasicos</p>
               <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
               <p class="descripcion"> Tradicionales molletes; bolillo con mantequilla, frijoles refritos y queso manchego o si lo prefiere puede agregar ingrediente extra de su elección.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="platillo">
               <p class="nombre"> Moyetes Clasicos</p>
               <p class="precio">$58.00</p>
               <p class="descripcion"> Tradicionales molletes; bolillo con mantequilla, frijoles refritos y queso manchego o si lo prefiere puede agregar ingrediente extra de su elección.</p>
            </div>
          
             </article>
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por contestar, si entiendo lo que dices solo que lo que yo quiero centrar es la palabra de Desayunos. Espero me puedas ayudar

Comment: Entonces primero apunta al articule y despues a p

Comment: lo hice amigo y no me quedo, tal vez algo me este estorbando o este agregando algo mal

Comment: Revisa muy bien la estrucutura que maneja, algo debes de tener. El punto es aplicar el centrado al contenedor de desayunos. Verifica también que otro estilo no lo esté afectado o con la propiedad de !importan puede funcionar.